# Has the paradox 4.5 database file encryption ever been broken?

Tags: historical

As the encryption of the paradox 4.5 database files is from around the late eighties or early nineties, I would have thought it would have been broken by now, but I've only seen tools to brute force (or use a dictionary) to get the password.

Has it been broken in the sense that you can calculate the password from contents (though it may take some time to do so)?

What is the encryption based on?

Comment: From a very quick search, it supports DES, 3DES and Blowfish - although it also appears to be possible to remove the encryption without needing the password, which suggests a few flaws...

Comment: I don't think there is an option to chose which kind of encryption to use in the DOS database files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paradox databases have a built-in encryption-based security scheme which allows a master password to be defined for the table and many specialized auxiliary passwords to be defined for various uses it.
The original version used its own protection, and it was by-passable and the password could have been reset. Passwords for newer versions could no longer be reset. I am not sure from what version above this applies, so this is only a partial answer.
Also, take note that there were known backdoor passwords for some versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I'd hoped for a bit more, I'll accept this answer.